# Is there a way to derive Num class functions in own data type in Haskell?

Tags: class, haskell, deriving

Let's say I have a type declaration:

```
 data MyType = N Double | C Char | Placeholder
```

I want to be able to treat MyType as a Double whenever it's possible, with all the Num, Real, Fractional functions resulting in N (normal result) for arguments wrapped in the N constructor, and Placeholder for other arguments

```
> (N 5.0) + (N 6.0)
N 11.0
> (N 5.0) + (C 'a')
Placeholder
```

Is there a way to do this other than simply defining this class as an instance of those classes in a manner similar to:

```
instance Num MyType where
  (+) (N d1) (N d2) = N (d1+d2)
  (+) _ _ = Placeholder
  ...
```

(which seems counter-productive)?

Comment: There is no way to "derive" a `Num` instance. The closest thing you can do is to use Template Haskell. (Or just write a normal Haskell program to auto-generate the code you want.)

Comment: *counter-productive* as in *to much work* ? ... but no - look there are even other perfectly fine things you could do (handle `C _` and `Placeholder` as `N 0` for example) - so how should the compiler decide for you? - Just define something like a `map2` to abstract your operations on two numbers to help you out)

Comment: Have you considered using a standard applicative functor instead of that custom type?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, what are you getting at?

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic `deriving` available in [standard Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html):  currently, `deriving` is only available as defined by the compiler for specific Prelude typeclasses: `Read`, `Show`, `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, and `Bounded`.

The Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC) apparently has [extensions](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/GenericDeriving) that support generic `deriving`.  However, I don't know if it would actually save you any work to try and use them:  how many typeclasses do you need to derive a `Num` instance from?  And, are you sure that you can define an automatic scheme for deriving `Num` that will always do what you want?

As noted in the comments, you need to describe what your `Num` instance will do in any case.  And describing and debugging a general scheme is certain to be more work than describing a particular one.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this automatically, but I think what leftaroundabout could have been getting at is that you can use `Applicative` operations to help you.

```
data MyType n = N n | C Char | Placeholder deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

instance Applicative MyType where
  pure = N
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad MyType where
  N n >>= f = f n
  C c >>= _ = C c
  Placeholder >>= _ = Placeholder
```

Now you can write

```
instance Num n => Num (MyType n) where
  x + y = (+) <$> x <*> y
  abs = fmap abs
  ...
```

Comment: What I meant with “standard applicative functor” was something like `MaybeT (Either Char) Double`. But defining a functor yourself is of course also possible, though... have you checked that this actually fulfills the monad laws?